# Time Complexity of Looping over an ArrayList and putting values in HashMap vs. just searching the ArrayList

Tags: java, hashmap, time-complexity

If you start with an `ArrayList<Obj>`, is there a time benefit to for-looping over the `ArrayList` and putting the values into a `HashMap` with a useful key for searching? Or does the looping of the `ArrayList` pretty much negate any benefit you would gain by putting it in the `HashMap`?

I assume you'd still get a benefit if you were going to perform many searches on the new `HashMap`, but what about just one search?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For just one search there's no point in creating a `HashMap`, since the time it takes to build the `HashMap` would be linear (`O(n)`), which is the same time it takes to directly search the `ArrayList`.

Since creating the `HashMap` has some overhead beyond the time it would take to iterate over the `ArrayList`, a single search by directly iterating over the `ArrayList` should be faster than building the `HashMap` and then searching for some key (though asymptotically both operations should take the same time).

A `HashMap` is justified if you are going to use it multiple times. For example, if you perform `n` searches on an `ArrayList` of size `n`, it would take `O(n^2)` time (since each search would require `O(n)` time).

On the other hand, if you put the elements of the `ArrayList` in a `Map` and perform `n` searches on the `Map`, the running time would be `O(n)` (since each search would take expected constant time).

Comment: Big O notation is based on the number of elements in the set, not how many times the set is processed. For an ArrayList with n elements, a linear search, best case is O(1), average case is O(n/2), and worst case is O(n).

Comment: @nicomp I meant worst case, though even for the average case, O(n/2) is the same as O(n). You can't rely on the best case in complexity computations, so that O(1) is irrelevant.